# Order By one part of a union query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a UNION query, and I want just one part of union to be sorted

```
Query1
UNION
Query2
UNION
Query3
```

So, I want only to sort Query 2, by the third column. All 3 queries have 3 columns.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do sort in query2 and wrap query2 with parentheses?

Comment: I tried that and got the error "Missing right parenthesis"

Comment: Does `(Query2)`  give you "Missing right parenthesis"?

Comment: Can't be done. (Duplicate elimination...)

Comment: Can rows in one of the queries appear in the other queries? Or can a row only ever appear in a single query? E.g. if the values (1, 2, 3) were returned by query1, could (1, 2, 3) be returned by either query2 or query3? If a given row can only be produced by one of the queries, then those UNIONs should really be UNION ALLs, and it's entirely possible to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in Oracle to `ORDER BY` an UNIONed nested query. You got the explanation of APC for details.

You can use [subquery factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) to overcome this

```
WITH T2SORTED
AS
(SELECT id FROM T2 ORDER BY id)
SELECT id FROM T1
UNION
SELECT id FROM T2SORTED
UNION
SELECT id FROM T3
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/26b6b/6)

Comment: @user1936588 it may have worked, but it still makes absolutely no sense to do this, IMHO. Either Oracle will be clever enough to ignore the order by, or you will be forcing Oracle to do an extra, unnecessary step. And even if your result sets were unique to each other (ie a specific set of values can only appear in one of the queries), you're still not guaranteeing that the output will remain in the order you want it to.

Comment: If this makes no sense, his question makes no sense, which might be the case. I just answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

> "Is this possible?"

No. UNION is a set operator, so it will munge the result set of each query into a new result set of distinct records. The output of *Query 2* will no longer be identifiable as such.

The exception is if each sub-query produces a unique set of records in their own right, in which case you should use UNION ALL, which doesn't filter for duplicates. Although this leads onto a philosophical point: what does it mean to have part of a result set sorted and the rest unsorted? Literally, what would that look like?

Comment: `UNION is a set operator, so it will munge the result set of each query into a new result set of distinct records` ... this implies (at least, to me) that all set operators will do the same, except `UNION ALL` is a set operator but it doesn't distinct the records (and, incidentally, would allow the records of one of the queries to be ordered and the rest unordered). Semantics, perhaps, but `UNION is a set operator that munges ...` makes it clearer, IMHO.

Comment: In maths a set is a set of distinct objects so it could be argued that `union all` is a not a set operator :)  But then RDBMSs often play fast'n'loose with Set Theory

Comment: True on all counts! *{;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. And yes it is. You have to sort the entire union with the same `order by`, but there's nothing stopping you from adding a column or two to the whole union.

So let's say we have tables foo, bar, and baz. Each has columns A, B, and C. Let's use B as the one you want to sort. We'll order B by bar and baz. We'll also force all the results from A to come before all the results from B and put those before C's. We have to do this to make sure B's results are in order.

```
select a.foo
, a.bar
, a.baz
, 0 as primary_sort
, 0 as secondary_sort
from A
union
select b.foo
, b.bar
, b.baz
, 1 as primary_sort
, row_number() over (order by b.bar, b.baz) as secondary_sort
from B
union
select c.foo
, c.bar
, c.baz
, 2 as primary_sort
, 0 as secondary_sort
from C
order by primary_sort, secondary_sort;
```

Then if you don't want those sort columns passed along, you can wrap a select statement around it:

```
select foo, bar, baz from (
-- query from above WITHOUT the order by
) order by primary_sort, secondary_sort;
```

The key is that `primary_sort` has to be the same type in each query and so does `secondary_sort`. The `row_number()` function lets you add as many columns as you want to the sort and reduces it to a single number. So the `over (order by ... )` is what actually declares how you want to order the results from B.